# Python Pandas Dataframe manipulation to form larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Im looking to turn

```
pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','B'],
              'beginDate':['2017-01-01','2017-01-03'],
              'endDate':['2017-01-02','2017-01-05']})

    Id  beginDate   endDate
0   A   2017-01-01  2017-01-02
1   B   2017-01-02  2017-01-05
```

Into

```
pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
         'Date':['2017-01-01','2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-02',
                 '2017-01-03','2017-01-04','2017-01-05']})

    Date       Id
0   2017-01-01  A
1   2017-01-02  A
2   2017-01-03  A
3   2017-01-02  B
4   2017-01-03  B
5   2017-01-04  B
6   2017-01-05  B
```

The concept is to fill the second dataframe with all values between the begin and end date.

I can use a for loop successfully and append a new dataframe for each unique 'Id' but this is very slow.

The for loop uses the below by looping over each row.

```
def dfChange(uniqueId, startDate, endDate):

allDates = pd.date_range(startDate, endDate)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':allDates})
df['Id'] = uniqueId
return df
```

Is it possible to do this without using a for loop?

Comment: Where does the third 'A' id come from? There aren't any 'A' observations with 2017-01-03.

Comment: added an extra line. 'The concept is to fill the second dataframe with all values between the begin and end date.'

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for reshape first.

Then convert index to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Last [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html), call [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

All data are in `index`, so select no columns by `[[]]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','B'],
              'beginDate':['2017-01-01','2017-01-02'],
              'endDate':['2017-01-03','2017-01-05']})
print (df)
  Id   beginDate     endDate
0  A  2017-01-01  2017-01-03
1  B  2017-01-02  2017-01-05

df = df.melt('Id', value_name='Date', var_name='a').set_index('Date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df=df.groupby('Id').resample('B')[[]].ffill().reset_index()
print (df)
  Id       Date
0  A 2017-01-01
1  A 2017-01-02
2  A 2017-01-03
3  B 2017-01-02
4  B 2017-01-03
5  B 2017-01-04
6  B 2017-01-05
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need.  I had not seen the documentation for 'melt'.  Is it possible to ffill with just business days?

Comment: Yes, only change `resample('D')` to `resample('B')`

Comment: you may find using .count() is faster than .sum()

Comment: Yes - 10x faster :)

Comment: @user3420834 - can you check `(df.groupby('Id').resample('B')[[]].ffill().reset_index())` with your data? It can be a bit faster.

Comment: @user3420834 - and it was my first version - https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44845137/1 :)